# What is the difference between an integral which does not have a closed form and an integral which is not convergent?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What is the difference between "an integral which does not have a closed form" and "an integral which is not convergent"?

I am quite a bit confused with these two terms, please give the definition for these two terms too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up "indefinite integrals", or "antiderivatives", with "definite integrals".

An antiderivative of a function $f(x)$ is a function $F(x)$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$. When we say $$\int f(x) dx$$ has no closed form it usually means it cannot be expressed as an elementary function.

When we say a definite integral, more precisely an improper Riemann integral, doesn't converge, for example $$\int_a^{b^-} f(x) dx $$ or $$\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$$ we mean the limit as $t\to b^-$ or $t\to\infty$ in $$G(t)=\int_a^t f(x) dx$$ fails to exist, that is, it either diverges to $\pm \infty$ or oscillates.

As an example, $$\int_0^{1^-} \frac{dx}{1-x}$$ $$\int_a^\infty \sin x dx$$ $a\in \Bbb R$, fail to exist, while $$\int \frac{dt}{\log t}$$ and $$\int\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$ have no closed form expressions.

Comment: Thank you very much +1 and best answer

Answer (score 3):

A (indefinite) integral has a closed form if it can be written in terms of a set of prescribed functions (i.e., polynomials, exponentials, trigonometric, etc).

A (definite) integral doesn't converge if its value isn't finite.

All combinations are possible.

An example of integral with closed form that doesn't converge is
$$\int_0^1 \frac{d x}{x}$$

An example of integral that converges but doesn't have a closed form is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} d x = \sqrt{\pi}
$$